# How to Check Rechargeable Battery NiMH Status with Microcontroller?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, battery-operated

I created a device, based on an Arduino Uno, which runs on 6 rechargeable NiMH batteries. Now I would like to add a check, if the batteries have enough power left, to warn with a signal when the batteries needs recharging.

As I understand, the voltage of the batteries will slowly go down, until they drop under the minimum required level.

**How is a battery load level check implemented? What kind of elements do I need?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most accurate way to know how much energy is left in a battery is to monitor the voltage, current, and temperature over time, then use knowledge of that particular chemistry to estimate remaining energy.  There are ICs which do parts of this, sometimes called battery *fuel guage* ICs.  Of course you can do the same thing with a microcontroller, but it takes constant A/D readings and the algorithm can be complicated, depending on how accurate you want to be.

A much simpler but less accurate way is to just monitor voltage.  NiMH cells start at about 1.4 to 1.5 V right after being charged, quickly drop to 1.2 or so, go down only slowly over most of the discharge cycle, then drop quickly at the end of charge.  Usually you stop discharging at 900 mV or so.  Letting the voltage of any cell get less than that can risk permanent damage.

You could simply pick a voltage around 1.0 to 1.1 V and decide to warn the user when the battery gets that low, then go dead at 900 mV.  The best levels depend on your load.

Of course you need to consult the datasheet for whatever particular batteries you are using.  The manufacturer will give you discharge plots at various currents, tell you how low you can go without damage, etc.  As always **read the datasheet**.

Comment: The Arduino Uno has analog inputs which measure 0-5V. Could I simply use two resistors to make a voltage divider from ~9V into a safe range for one of these analog inputs?

Comment: @Flov: You could, but you have to be careful about quiescient current.  If that's a issue, you may want a high side FET switch to turn on the divider.  That way it is off most of the time.  You only need to turn it on a few us around each measurement, which doesn't have to be more often than 1 s if you're only measuring voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is a little late, but I have had this same problem and found a solution that looks like it will work great.  Basically, the reference voltage on the Arduino is based off of Vcc (unless you provide an alternative Vref), which makes measuring Vcc very difficult.  To fix this, you can base your measurements off of the internal Vref of 1.1v.  Even though the internal Vref is smaller than Vcc, you can still use it to calibrate the Vcc measurement so that it is accurate.  This has a lot of advantages for things other than battery measurement as it can keep the voltage readings steady even if you don't have a clean Vcc source.  Please note that I did not come up with this solution, I merely found it here:

[https://provideyourown.com/2012/secret-arduino-voltmeter-measure-battery-voltage/][1]

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a voltage divider using 2 resistors to decrease the voltage to the range that mcu can meager, and connect the output to the ABC pin of mcu.

Comment: You are overlooking the quiescent current concern already raised in the answer posted a day previously.  Generally, an answer posted after others isn't useful unless it covers something they've overlooked.